# Create new cell spaces in record sheet every new order

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to make cell spaces every time Saved Invoices go into record sheet.

Instead the last cell of item and qty get overwritten by the save.
And it didn't go as a whole one order if I try to sort it from individual table.

I am trying to make something like this:
[image]

The full code

```vb
Sub Save()
Dim SimpanInvoice As Object
Set SimpanInvoice = Sheet3.Range("A20000").End(xlUp)

If Sheet4.Range("Invonomer").Value = "" _
  Or Sheet4.Range("Invotgl").Value = "" _
  Or Sheet4.Range("Invoto").Value = "" _
  Or Sheet4.Range("Invoalamat").Value = "" Then

    Call MsgBox("Harap isi data dengan lengkap", vbInformation, "Isi Data")

Else
    SimpanInvoice.Offset(1, 0).Value = Sheet4.Range("Invonomer").Value
    SimpanInvoice.Offset(1, 1).Value = Sheet4.Range("Invotgl").Value
    SimpanInvoice.Offset(1, 2).Value = Sheet4.Range("Invoto").Value
    SimpanInvoice.Offset(1, 3).Value = Sheet4.Range("Invoalamat").Value
    SimpanInvoice.Offset(1, 4).Value = Sheet4.Range("Keterangan").Value
    SimpanInvoice.Offset(1, 5).Value = Sheet4.Range("item1").Value
    SimpanInvoice.Offset(1, 6).Value = Sheet4.Range("Qty_1").Value
    SimpanInvoice.Offset(2, 5).Value = Sheet4.Range("item2").Value
    SimpanInvoice.Offset(2, 6).Value = Sheet4.Range("Qty_2").Value

    Call MsgBox("Data SuratTagihan Telah Di Simpan", vbInformation, "Data Surat Tagihan")

    Sheet4.Range("Invonomer").Value = ""
    Sheet4.Range("Invotgl").Value = ""
    Sheet4.Range("Invoto").Value = ""
    Sheet4.Range("Invoalamat").Value = ""
    Sheet4.Range("Keterangan").Value = ""
    Sheet4.Range("item1").Value = ""
    Sheet4.Range("Qty_1").Value = ""
    Sheet4.Range("item2").Value = ""
    Sheet4.Range("Qty_2").Value = ""

End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your ColA is not fully populated, so you could add a loop to make sure the row you're working on is empty

```vb
Dim SimpanInvoice As Object

Set SimpanInvoice = Sheet3.Range("A20000").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
'make sure the row we're on is completely empty (not just empty in ColA) 
Do While Application.CountA(SimpanInvoice.EntireRow) > 0
    Set SimpanInvoice = SimpanInvoice.Offset(1) 'next row down 
Loop
'start populating the row
SimpanInvoice.Value = Sheet4.Range("Invonomer").Value
SimpanInvoice.Offset(0, 1).Value = Sheet4.Range("Invotgl").Value
'etc etc
```

Comment: ok, somehow i did it able to give cell spaces so it looks tidier thank you, but i still couldnt sort it as a nice whole order if i ask for a summary or printout history data for a specific date or specific invoice number. but still kudos for you

can i ask you for a suggestion, should i create horizontal item record or vertical just like this for PrintOut ?